# replacing <img> by <img></img> in a string

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace every `<img>` tag with closing `<img></img>` tags in a string. The string is actually an html document where the img tag are generated by me and always look like this :

```
<img src="some_source.jpg" style="some style attributes and values">
```

Src is user input so it can be anything.
I made a regex expression, not sure if correct because it's my first time using it but upon testing it was working. The problem is that I don't know how to keep the content of the `src`.

```
/<img\ssrc=".+?"\sstyle=".+?">/g
```

But I have difficulties replacing the tags in the string.

and all I got is this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/<img\\ssrc=\".+?\"\\sstyle=\".+?\">/g");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    List<String> imgStrArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        imgStrArr.add(m.group(0));
    }
    Matcher m2 = p.matcher(str);
```

Comment: replacing `<img>` tags by `<img></img>` makes bad things worse.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  What do you mean ? I can't parse the string into a Document class if those are not closing. Did you downvote ?

Comment: why do you want to do this? `<img>` isn't an enclosing tag, so `</img>` is syntactically **wrong**.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Because parsing the string into an xml throws error without enclosing tags.

Comment: ... XML knows *void* tags, ie. things like `<img src="http://bla.com/i.png" />`.

Comment: Also, I never tire to repeat: HTML is **not** valid XML, unless it's specified to be that. Don't try to parse it as XML.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes but my input has no void tags. I generate the html myself, put it in the document with js, then on submission take back the document. What is in it ? Not void tags, just tags <img> even though when I put it in in the first place I specified void tags.

Comment: if you produce the HTML yourself, *why the hell* didn't you write proper `<img />` tags?!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I did that's the whole point. Browser just changed it into not closing tag.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks though upon inspection I noticed not every browser did parse what I gave the same way so I've other problems going on.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry to bother but you seemed to say what I'm doing is wrong because it's not a "legal" html file but it works. In the top of your head can this result in any issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match:

```
(<img[^>]+>)
```

And replace with `$1</img>`

**Code:**

```
str = str.replaceAll("(<img[^>]+>)", "$1</img>");
```

**Edit:** Considering @MarcusMüller's advice you can do the following:

Regex: `(<img[^>]+)>`

Replace with `$1/>`

**Code:**

```
str = str.replaceAll("(<img[^>]+)>", "$1/>");
```

Comment: He will wreck the HTML file.. citing http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element : * Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.* `<img>` is a void element.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the <img></img> tags WILL be parsed by the browser. At least on chrome, I didn't test with others so far as this wasn't obvious to me this could be error prone.

Comment: @Ced, that's because browser are **incredibly** tolerant against both invalid HTML (which `</img>` is) and invalid XML (which `</img>` is, because the DTD forbids that).

Comment: @MarcusMüller glad that you think so :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller you are right but do you suggest any other method? You probably won't like what you read but well : I've an iframe where user can generate content by clicking buttons. I do the insertion via javascript, upon insertion I also insert FALSE (lol this is the part you ain't gonna like) tags like <tobedeleted></..>. I then parse the document as String to a Document (object representing xml). I delete the tags I don't want. When parsing from String to Document I get an error if a non closing <img> tag is present.

Comment: @karthikmanchala Didn't work.  What is $1 btw ? I'm not sure where my src is kept is that what it is about ? doc says it's end of a line.

Comment: @Ced `$1` is the reference to the 1st captured group.. can you show the code you wrote to test this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Pattern and Matcher classes, you can use the regular replace method like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(<img.*?>)", "$1</img>");
```

**[IdeOne working demo](https://ideone.com/rwxvG9)**